# Closed form for an infinite series wanted.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, infinity

I’m trying to get a closed form for

$$\sum_{n=k}^\infty n^{-\beta}\;,$$

where $\beta>\frac12$ and $k>0$.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't converge until $\beta$ exceeds 1.

Comment: For the most part, closed form is elusive with elementary functions.

Answer (score 2):

You could subtract the formula for the sum of the first $k$ numbers to the $nth$ power from the [Riemann Zeta function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function). As pointed out in the comments, this is only valid when it converges.

Comment: The first $k-1$ terms are not a geometric series.

Comment: Yeah, definitely not geometric.  If it were geometric, the exponent would be changing.

Comment: Sorry about that it should be sum of first $n$ squares, cubes, etc.